# In a repeater, how should I add an image and a label and align them vertically?

Tags: c#

I am displaying in a repeater a image and a textbox but the problem is that i am trying to make it look like in the image to the right so the image is to eft and text to the right of the image
i am trying to make it working user  but then only the image if fine on a new line but the label is wierd that the problem. this is my code please take a look and se what i have done wrong and maybe help me to solve my problem. Here is the code snippet!

```
if (vData.SkillNameOther != null && vData.SkillLevel == "Beginner")
{
    lbl.Text = vData.SkillNameOther+ "<br />"; 
    img.ImageUrl = @"~/_layouts/images/Cv.Knowit/pie-1-4.png";

    RepeaterDataBase.Controls.Add(lbl);
    RepeaterDataBase.Controls.Add(img);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you are adding the controls in the wrong order, the label should be added 2nd.

Even so, the label would still align bottom. Then you need to vertical align:

[Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

Another option would be to use a table (see post below) and vertical align the cells:

[How to create a three column table in ASP.Net Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442897/how-to-create-a-three-column-table-in-asp-net-repeater)