# Create a table of input fields and date fields from user selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a program that asks the user how many fields(tests, assignments, and practicals).

I so far have a hardcoded table with 5(maximum) fields for tests, assignments, and practicals which will become visible once I have the user selection.

e.g if the user selects 3 tests, only txtTest1, 2 and 3 will become visible.

What I actually want to do is have a dynamic page which creates the table according to the user selection.

The problem I am facing is creating this table with input fields I can pull from in the code of the webpage.

Could anyone help, please?

I would like to know if this is possible and how before i code further.

This is what I have so far:

The webpage before user input:

[image: beforeUserInput]

After user selection and button click:

[image: After user selection]

In the code, I would like to have something like this:

```
Test test1 = new Test();
test1.Weighting = txtTest1W.Text;
test1.Date = txtTest1D.Text;

MAH.AddTest(test1);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You could use a [Repeater control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) and declare an [ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) - then simply populate a collection of (blank) items and bind it to the Repeater.

Comment: @Filburt Sorry for the delayed response. How would I be able to create blank items and access them on the code side, if you follow what I'm saying

Comment: If you did not already find out from Cory's answer - this is the core of asp.net: handle collections of objects/data code-side and bind them to page controls. Check any of the samples for the controls Cory mentioned and you will see how it is meant to work.

Comment: @Filburt Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into using a [DataList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, take a look at this article on [Deciding When to Use the DataGrid, DataList or Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx). Finally, You may want to look at some of the answers here: [How to create a three column table in ASP.Net Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442897/how-to-create-a-three-column-table-in-asp-net-repeater).

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated. Got it working.